# Conflicting jars from AWS SDK for Java and my Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, amazon-web-services, jar

I have a Java web project that I deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It has the AWS SDK for Java libraries as well as my Maven dependencies.  There are conflicting versions of a few jars. For example:
AWS SDK: httpclient-4.2.3.jar
Maven:   httpclient-4.3.jar

I don't run into the conflict locally, but when I deploy to AWS, both jars are deployed. The website doesn't work in this state, so I have to remove the old ones manually, then do a restart.

Not sure what the best option is, if it's a project setting/exclusion, or a setting for the deployment.

Comment: Please show your pom, cause maven itself has a dependency to httpclient but these are different than the project dependencies and will not be deployed. May be you get the dependency via a transitvie dependency in your project...may be you should check via `mvn dependency:tree` to see what is in your project.

Comment: Can you list your .classpath and /WEB-INF/lib contents? And why aren't you using [beanstalker](http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin?) to deploy from a CI environment? (ok, I know I know)

Comment: Thanks. My local /WEB-INF/lib is empty. When I deploy, it contains both versions of httpclient until I delete one. In my pom, I have:
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.3</version>
</dependency>